# Is it legal for a business in the US to charge to make change?

Tags: united-states, currency, legal-tender

Is it legal in the US, for a business to charge a fee to make change (cash to smaller denominations, e.g., taking a dollar bill and giving back coins) or the reverse (e.g., taking coins and returning bills)?

For example, would it be legal for a business to offer to change a dollar bill into three quarters?

Comment: For the "reverse" direction, there's a large company whose entire business model is that: https://www.coinstar.com/.  If it was illegal I think we'd have heard about it by now.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, you can charge for providing a service

Even if many businesses provide that service for free.